# error expected expression before "STACK"

Tags: c, stack

```
typedef struct student *std_ptr;

   struct student
    {
        int number;
        std_ptr next;
    };
    typedef std_ptr STACK;

    create_stack(void)
    {
        STACK S;
        S = (STACK) malloc( sizeof( struct student ) );

        if(S == NULL) printf("out of space!");
        return S;
    }

    void push(int x, STACK S)
    {
        std_ptr tmp;
        tmp = (std_ptr) malloc(sizeof(struct student));

        if(tmp == NULL) printf("out of space!");

        else
        {
            tmp -> number = x;
            tmp -> next = S -> next;
            S -> next = tmp;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        push(12058010,STACK S);
        return 0;
    }
```

Im trying to call function and I get **error: expected expression before stack**.I also tried to call the function like that

```
    int main()
    {
        push(12058010,S);
        return 0;
    }
```

This time I get **error: 'S' undeclared(first use in this function)**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are in the most serious need of reading a beginner C book or tutorial.

Comment: Your text on how to write a function and declare its parameters surely has an example of how to *invoke* that function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define the variable `s` by doing:

   ```
   STACK s;
   ```
2. Initialise it:

   ```
   s = create_stack();
   ```
3. Test whether the initialisation succeeded:

   ```
   if (NULL == s)
   {
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   ```
4. Use it by calling `push()` like this:

   ```
   push(12058010, s);
   ```

All together this could look like this:

```
int main(void)
{   
    STACK s = create_stack(); /* This merges step 1 and 2. */
    if (NULL == s)
    {
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    push(12058010, s);
    return EXIT_SUCCES;
}
```

Comment: Also, function `create_stack()` should declare its return type: `STACK create_stack()` or else it defaults to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`S` is neither in the global scope nor in the scope of `main()`.

I suspect you meant to write `STACK S = create_stack();` as the first statement in `main()`.

Don't forget to `free` the allocated memory as well.